# PHP Double Quotes In Array Key

Tags: php

I know this is really bad practice, but it's already been put in place because it is an existing system. Anyways, I have a table that has an id and a description. What the code does is it creates an array from this table, but to make it easy to search, we made the description they key and the id the value. Now the issue is that the description contains double quotes, example 4"x6", and that is preventing the program from finding the id. Is there any special escape sequence that I can use to get around this issue?

Here is an example of simplified code:

```
$my_ary = array('4"x6"'=>22, 'test'=>3);

echo $my_ary['4"x6"']; // Does not work
echo $my_ary['test']; // Works

$quote_key = '4"x6"';
echo $my_ary[$quote_key]; // Does not work
```

Hopefully with that example that will help out my explination.

this is with version 5.2.6-3ubuntu4.2 of PHP

Comment: Works for me: http://ideone.com/8eurD

Comment: what do the error logs say? or error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually works for me on php 5.3.2

Comment: I didn't realize it at the time, but at some point when my query pulled back the data, something was converting all the quotes to &quot;, and I didn't think about looking at the source until I lost hours looking at the wrong thing. Anyways, it does work and you're the first one to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me under PHP 5.3.2.

Comment: I also just tested the code under an older version of PHP, v5.1.6, and it worked there, as well.